# php determine if a variable is an open file handle

Tags: php

i am currently using `is_resource()`to determine whether a variable is an open file handle.

Is this correct or is there an alternative (better) way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That can give you a lot of false positives, like for example database resources.

You should use [`get_resource_type`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php) instead.

Comment: so the absolute best way to check if a variable is an open file handle would be if (get_resource_type($myVar) == 'handle') { // my code here }

Comment: @user1189880 No, if you look at the manual, it should be `file` for a file handle, so `get_resource_type($myVar) === 'file'`.

Comment: Oooooops, that really was a typo. Honest :)  Is there no constant in php instead of using a string 'file' ?

Comment: @user1189880 Not that I know of :-)

Comment: thats a shame, its the only thing putting me off

Comment: the comments in the doc are a bit disconcerting as well, as they mentioned getting 'stream' instead of 'file'

Comment: @ernie thanks your right i just noticed that in the comments.  Now im not sure what to do

Comment: i get 'stream' im on php 5.3.10-1 and ubuntu os

Comment: so i guess we need to use: if(get_resource_type($myVar) === 'file' || get_resource_type($myVar) === 'stream') {
}

Comment: @user1189880 As long as you don't have to distinguish them from other streams ;-)

Comment: ok i see, its now getting more complicated again.  Surely there must be an elegant way to check if a variable is an open file handle?

Comment: I know that this is an old post, but for me I found that for a closed handle, `get_resource_type($handle)` returns  `'Unknown'`